# bind dropdownwith country names from json in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a json string like [{Name:"Russia",Value:6},{Name:"USA",Value:"8"}]
 in controller how can i convert this list to select list item to bind to a dropdownlist? 
and i have to populate state list depending upon the selected country using ajax post back? 
anybody give some sample on this

Comment: It's not a JSON. At least not valid one - Its just JavaScript array.

Answer (score 0):

Below is example for bind dropdown from your json object. In this example GetCountry is function from controller which is return json object and below script is iterate json object and bind the dropdown.

**Script:-**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetCountry", "Dropdown")', function (result) {
        var ddlCountryId = $('#CountryId');
        ddlCountryId.empty();
        $(result).each(function () {
            ddlCountryId.append(
            $('<option/>', {
                value: this.Id
            }).html(this.Nome)
        );
        });
    });
 });
```

**View syntax:-**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()))
```

**Controller Function:-**

```
   public ActionResult GetCountry()
    {
        var sites = new[]
            {
                new { Id = "6", Nome = "Russia" },
                new { Id = "8", Nome = "USA" }
            };
        return Json(sites, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. 
In one of my controller actions am receiving the Json string from a web service like
    string x = weservicecalltogetcountrylist();
here i need to convert the Json string to select list item and store it to viewbag.country property 

how can i read the values from json string x and convert it to selectlist items?
whether i need any class like below to convert the json to selectlist items?
    class country
    {
        string name;
        int value;
    }

Comment: returning json string from webservice is like [{"Name":"Russia","Value":"6"},{"Name":"USA","Value":"8"}]